# Is my motherboard dead?

Tags: motherboard

So I came back from holidays and now my computer won't start anymore. I already checked the power supply but it's working. Before buying a new motherboard I'd like to know for sure if my motherboard is dead. How do I do it properly?

---

My motherboard is a GA-B75M-D3H if it helps.

Comment: You have to give details as to what exactly happens when you try to turn it on and what you have tried to fix it. What all have you checked? As it is your question is unanswerable except by guess

Comment: If you have another working PC, you can swap out components to try and figure out what the broken part is.  So, how do you know the power supply is working?  Did you swap it into a working PC and saw it all work properly there?  Do the same with RAM, storage, etc.  It's hard if you only have one PC, or if you have PCs with different CPUs or sockets.

Comment: Well, I turn it on but no fan or led works. Nor the I/O button neither the reset button seem to make a difference. I measured the voltage of my power supply and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I plugged out every bit of hardware on my motherboard and still nothing. I haven't really tried to repair it, as I don't have an idea what to do to repair a completely non reactive motherboard.

Comment: Generally motherboard failures are not repairable, unfortunately.  If you have another power supply, give it a try, and if the LED and fan don't respond to that either, you motherboard is probably dead.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage unfortunately it is my only desktop computer. I shortend the power supply and measured the voltage using a multimeter.

Comment: Did you measure the power supply under load? I've definitely seen power supplies fail in such a way that they still produced the right voltage when idle, but put any kind of load on them and the voltage would drop below spec. Basically they lost the ability to deliver any amperage at that voltage.